# Is there a C++ equivalent to "The GNU C Reference Manual"?

Tags: c++, gnu

After reading [The GNU C Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.pdf), I could easily start writing my first simple programs with a strong theoretical foundation. Is there a similar document targeting C++?

Comment: I guess you could find something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Something like  https://en.cppreference.com/ ? Quite usefull when you need reference for specific functions/classes/keywords/etc.

Comment: Note that the GNU C Reference manual covers C90 and C99 (and GNU extensions to C90 and C99). it was produced in 2009 and therefore doesn't cover C11 (though it was last given a copyright date in 2015).  It's good; it just doesn't cover the current versions of C.  For many people, especially beginners, that won't matter.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Doesn't it cover the GNU C variant of the standard? i.e. with the GCC-specific additions?